# Ajax file stops executing

Tags: php, ajax

I have this snippet of AJAX code which is working correctly in the fact its updating my database, only once its done its not executing the rest of my code...

```
$(".getPoint").click(function()
{        
   var theid = $(this).attr("id");
   var onlyID = theid.split("_");
   var onlyID = onlyID[1];
   var credoff = parseInt($(this).children('input.credoff:hidden').val());

    $.ajax({            
      url: 'do.php',
      type: 'POST',          
      data: "userID=" + onlyID + "&credoff=" + credoff,
      success: function(data) {
          if(data != "success1" && data != "success5") {
               $("#" + theid).text(data);  
          }else{

              $("#thediv_" + onlyID).fadeOut("slow");
              $('#creditsBalance').fadeOut("slow");
              newbalance = parseInt($('#creditsBalance').text());

          if(data != "success5") { 
               newbalance = newbalance+credoff;
              }else{
                newbalance = newbalance+5;
              }
          alert ('hi');

              $('#creditsBalance').text(newbalance);
              $('#creditsBalance').fadeIn("slow");
              $("#" + theid).text("Done"); 
          }
      },
      beforeSend: function()
      {
            $("#" + theid).text("Working...");                  
      },
      error: function()
      {           
        $("#" + theid).text("Failed...Click to Retry");           
      }          
    });
});
```

The line

```
if(data != "success5") { 
    newbalance = newbalance+credoff;
}else{
    newbalance = newbalance+5;
}
alert ('hi');
```

Updates my DB but then I dont receive an alert, Is this enough code for anybody to see where im going wrong?

Comment: Have you fired up a JavaScript console (Firebug for example) in the browser and seen if there are any script errors?

Comment: @Jeff, Yeah I have only its all running fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to send the alert on success change your snippet like this

```
if(data != "success5") { 
    newbalance = newbalance+credoff;
}else{
    newbalance = newbalance+5;
    alert ('hi');
}
```

this way if it is 'success5' you will get your alert

Comment: I've tried that and that works, but I need to add the code...
                  $('#creditsBalance').text(newbalance);
                  $('#creditsBalance').fadeIn("slow");
                  $("#" + theid).text("Done"); ...which should then update a div on my page with the new value...

Comment: simply add this code inplace of the alert(), the alert was there for debugging purposes right? so just replace it with your code

Answer (score 1):

Your server may be adding newlines or other spacing which screws up string comparisons, be sure to trim whitespace before doing such operations:

```
success: function(data) {
  data = data.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

That line doesn't update the database at all. The php code that updates the database is already executed. You'll need to find out where the point is reached where the if begins. If it isn't, the problem could be in the php code (after the part where the database is updated) or it could be in the javascript code, either in specifying the correct `OnSuccess` event handler for the AJAX request, or in the actual code in that event handler.

In this case, it could very well be that newbalance is not defined inside the event handler, so executing the line

```
newbalance = newbalance + whatever;
```

will cause an error.

Easiest thing to try: put an `alert('yoyoyo');` at the top of the success handler. If you don't get that message, the event is not called.

Make sure you test using FireBug or a similar tool, to check if you don't get any syntax errors or other errors. If you don't *and* you don't get the message, the event handler is not called and the problem probably lies in the server code.

Comment: I understand this line doesnt update my php, Ill try adding the alert, thanks